# Add leading 0 to a conditional VARCHAR column

Tags: sql, varchar, vertica, leading-zero

I have a string column where I want to add a leading zero on the basis of a certain condition.
All columns are Varchar and need to stay as such for joins etc.

Example Table:

| Category | ID |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0516E24 |
| A | 51733F |
| A | F383036 |
| B | 5290W |
| C | 058Z2 |
| C | S36.98 |

I am essentially looking to add leading '0' to any code that starts with the character '5'. **I do not want add a leading zero to any other value that does NOT start with '5' such as the *F383036* and *S36.98* values seen above.**

I tried CASE WHEN statement but I got an error (ERROR: Could not convert "" to float8)

My code:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CODE LIKE '5%' THEN '0' ELSE '' END + CODE AS CODE
FROM table
```

I am looking for the updated table to look like below where I have bolded the corrected values.

| Category | ID |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0516E24 |
| A | **051733F** |
| A | F383036 |
| B | **05290W** |
| C | 058Z2 |
| C | S36.98 |

I appreciate your help, I am completely lost. Thank you!

Comment: Can you update your question to include the SQL `CASE` statement that you've tried?

Comment: Show us your `case` _expression_ attempt!

Comment: BTW, which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh I am using Vertica

Answer (score 1):

It's Vertica. Vertica is ANSI compliant, and uses the double bar, `||` for concatenation, unlike Access and SQL Server. Change your code to:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN LEFT(CODE,1)= '5' 
    THEN '0' 
    ELSE '' 
  END || CODE AS CODE
FROM table
```

The somewhat misleading message 'Could not convert "" to float8' comes from the fact that the `+` operator you use in your attempt expects numeric literals to the left and the right of it. Vertica is trying to implicitly re-cast the string to float before trying the addition operation.

Comment: Just a min or comment. `||` is ANSI SQL, but not LEFT().

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CODE LIKE '5%' THEN CONCAT('0', CODE) ELSE CODE END AS CODE
FROM table
```